# Creating dotted layer with bigger dots using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I need to create a whole arrangement of symbolized layers for various descriptions. Some included dotted patterns. Stripes with various colours I have sorted, and I know on adding layers there is dots, with dot density, but the dots are just still way too small I need them to be far larger, and visible to the eye without having to zoom in to even see dots are there. I tried doing it with marker points, which looks better, but the dots get bigger when zoomed out and that's no good either.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Point Pattern Fill, and Map Units (or Meters at Scale) as the units for size, this will make the points scale dependent so look larger zoomed in. [image]